# Regex Match string after keyword between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, source-engine

I need to match value after keyword between double quote
for example:

```
zoom_sensitivity "2"
sensitivity "99"
m_rawinput "0"
m_righthand "0"
```

also with different spacing:

```
sensitivity"99"m_rawinput"0"zoom_sensitivity"2"m_righthand"0"
```

another example:

```
sensitivity"99" m_rawinput "0"
m_righthand "0"
zoom_sensitivity"2"
```

i want to get `99` value in both scenarios after *sensitivity* keyword or chosen one

What i tried is:
`[\n\r]*["|\n\r\s]sensitivity\s*"([^\n\r\s]*)"`

but it does not match if the keyword is in the first line or before any whitespace/double quote and with inline code it match more than just *99* value.
I believe Source Engine parse it similar from their .cfg files and maybe there is better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex and capture your digits from group1,

```
\bsensitivity\s*"(\d+)"
```

As you want to select `99` which is only after `sensitivity` as whole word, word boundaries `\b` needs to be used surrounding the word, like `\bsensitivity\b` and `\s*` allows matching optional whitespace between the word and then `"` matches a doublequote then `(\d+)` matches one or more digits and captures in group1 and finally `"` matches the closing doublequote.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0bU1V/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply this:

`(\w+)\s?"(\d+)"`

Which outputs

```
zoom_sensitivity "2"    zoom_sensitivity    2
sensitivity "99"        sensitivity         99
m_rawinput "0"          m_rawinput          0
m_righthand "0"         m_righthand         0
sensitivity"99"         sensitivity         99
m_rawinput"0"           m_rawinput          0
zoom_sensitivity"2"     zoom_sensitivity    2
m_righthand"0"          m_righthand         0
sensitivity"99"         sensitivity         99
m_rawinput "0"          m_rawinput          0
m_righthand "0"         m_righthand         0
zoom_sensitivity"2"     zoom_sensitivity    2
```

For this:

```
zoom_sensitivity "2"
sensitivity "99"
m_rawinput "0"
m_righthand "0"
also with different spacing:

sensitivity"99"m_rawinput"0"zoom_sensitivity"2"m_righthand"0"
another example:

sensitivity"99" m_rawinput "0"
m_righthand "0"
zoom_sensitivity"2"
```

You can put it into an object and then query that object later:

```js
var parse = function(content) {
  var myregexp = /(\w+)\s*"(\d+)"/mg;
  var match = myregexp.exec(content);
  while (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group n: match[n]
    console.log(match[1] + " => " + match[2]);
    // re-run the regex for the next item
    match = myregexp.exec(content);
  }
}

parse(document.getElementById("example1").innerHTML);
console.log("-----------");
parse(document.getElementById("example2").innerHTML);
console.log("-----------");
parse(document.getElementById("example3").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="example1">
zoom_sensitivity "2"
sensitivity "99"
m_rawinput "0"
m_righthand "0"
</div>

<div id="example2">
sensitivity"99"m_rawinput"0"zoom_sensitivity"2"m_righthand"0"
</div>

<div id="example3">
sensitivity"99" m_rawinput "0"
m_righthand "0"
zoom_sensitivity"2"
</div>
```